# Closed maps with non-compact fibers

Tags: general-topology, compactness, closed-map

A geometric example of a non-closed map with compact fibers is obtained by taking a finite covering map and removing a point upstairs. This fragmentation of the fiber destroys closedness but retains compactness of fibers.

What are some **geometric** examples of a *closed map with non-compact fibers*? I'm not interested in things like the terminal map of an uncountable discrete space. Hoping for some pictures, the closer to manifolds the better.

My motivation is to justify the intuition for proper (universally closed separated) maps as "complete" families of compact spaces. I want to understand how a "mere" closed map might fail to warrant this description when the fibers aren't compact.

Comment: Do you that all fibers are non-compact?

Comment: @PaulFrost yes, otherwise you can take a closed map and just add a point downstairs and an uncountable discrete space above it. Do you have a geometric example in mind?

Comment: There are trivial examples like $f : \mathbb R \to *$, but I am sure that you want other examples. You should try to make this more precise. Perhaps a connected range with more than one point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a final answer, but it shows that there are serious restrictions for possible examples.

A map $p : Y \to X$ is not a closed map provided

(1) $X$ contains a countable non-closed set $A$ such that for each $x \in A$ the  fiber $F_x = p^{-1}(x)$ is a closed non-compact subset of $Y$. Note that if all one-point subsets of $A$ are closed in $X$, then the $F_x$ are automatically closed.

(2) $Y$ can be written as $Y = \bigcup_{m=1}^\infty C_m$ with relatively compact open $C_m \subset Y$ such that $C_m  \subset C_{m+1}$. Note that we do not assume that compact includes Hausdorff; if you want to assume this, then $Y$ is nothing else than a Hausdorff locally compact and $\sigma$-compact space. Example: $Y$ locally compact, separable and metrizable.

Proof. Write $A = \{ x_n \}$. For each $n$ the fiber $F_{x_n}$ is closed and non-compact, hence it cannot be contained in any $\overline{C}_m$. Define $Y_n = F_{x_n} \setminus C_n$ (which is nonempty and closed in $Y$) and $B = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty Y_n$. We show that $B$ is closed in $Y$. In fact, for $y \notin B$ there exists $m$ such that $y \in C_m$. For $n \ge m$ we have $Y_n \cap C_m \subset Y_n \cap C_n = \emptyset$. Hence $D = B \cap C_m = \left(\bigcup_{n=1}^{m-1} Y_n \right) \cap C_m$ is closed in $C_m$ and $U = C_m \setminus D = C_m \setminus B$ is an open neigborhood of $y$ not meeting $B$. But by construction $p(B) = A$.

Remark:

(1) implies that the set $N$ of all $x \in X$ with a non-compact fiber $F_x$ has an accumulation point (in fact, each $\xi \in \overline{A} \setminus A$ is an accumulation point). The converse is true if $X$ is $T_1$ and first countable: If $x$ is an accumulation point of $N$, then there exists a countable $A \subset N \setminus \{ x \}$ such that $x \in \overline{A}$, i.e. $A$ is not closed.

The map $p : (\mathbb Z \times \mathbb R) \cup (\mathbb R \times \{ 0 \}) \to \mathbb R, p(x,y) = x,$ is an example of closed map with infinitely many non-compact fibers.

Comment: This is very interesting! I wonder "how many" fibers a closed map forces to be compact under similar mild assumptions.

Comment: Dear Paul, would you mind lending your prowess and taking a look at [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/319180/69037)?

Comment: The requirements can be weakened a little.This gives a sort of answer to your question "how many" fibers have to be compact. I edited my answer. Concerning your question in mathoverflow: I do not have an idea how to remove the conditions on $X,Y$. I am sceptical whether this is possible.

Comment: Dear Paul, thank you very much for your insight! If you are willing, I opened [a room](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93356/room-for-arrow-and-paul-frost) to ask you about your skepticism about the MO problem.

Comment: Not at the moment, but I think tomorow.

Comment: to make sure I'm not missing something: it follows from your proposition that the set of points with closed non-compact fibers has no sequential limit points. So when $Y$ is first countable, this set consists of isolated points? If so, then removing a discrete set from the base of such a closed map makes it universally closed. This is very neat!

Comment: @Arrow In my answer I proved that if a map $p :Y \to X$ satisfies (1) and (2), then it is not closed. It seems that in your comment you consider closed maps $p : Y \to X$. Thus one of (1) or (2) cannot be satisfied. But I do not understand why for $Y$ first countable the set of closed non-compact fibers should be discrete *in general*. Of course , there are certainly conditions assuring this ...

Comment: Dear @Paul, in my comment I am considering a closed map satisfying (2). In this case (1) is not satisfied. Perhaps my question makes sense in this setting.

Comment: @Arrow Okay, I see. But I think you should have $X$ first countable.